# qlikview drag and drop columns issue

Tags: drag-and-drop, qlikview

I'm new to QV and I was wondering if you could help me out!

I have three new columns and when I drag the column to the correct place, it seems to move other columns that are on a different tab, I've tried sorting with the sort/dimensions and expressions tab but I'm not having any luck
Here are the columns that get moved with an arrow to where they should be.
[image]

Other column that got moved:
[image]

These are the new columns from the first tab that I added:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated
Terry

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :) I had to add the new columns to the expression table (doh!) lol